# Yeoman angular app npm install error not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, yeoman, karma-jasmine

I've searched far and wide for a solution to this but can't seem to find an answer. I've used Yeoman scaffolding many times before on my old Windows 8 PC but I can't get it working on my new Windows 8 PC.

I'm trying to scaffold an angular app using Yeoman. I did the following:

```
> npm install --global npm
> npm install --global yo bower grunt-cli
> npm install --global generator-angular
> mkdir mytodo && cd mytodo
> npm --version && yo --version && bower --version && grunt --version

2.5.1
1.4.6
1.4.1
grunt-cli v0.1.13
grunt v0.4.5

> yo angular
```

It runs up to the point where it runs bower install & npm install then shows a whole heap of errors. This is in the npm-debug.log file.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install' ]
2 info using npm@2.5.1
3 info using node@v0.12.1
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose config Skipping project config: C:\Users\melon/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
6 error install Couldn't read dependencies
7 verbose stack Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\melon\package.json'
7 verbose stack     at Error (native)
8 verbose cwd C:\Users\melon
9 error Windows_NT 6.2.9200
10 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
11 error node v0.12.1
12 error npm  v2.5.1
13 error path C:\Users\melon\package.json
14 error code ENOPACKAGEJSON
15 error errno -4058
16 error package.json ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\melon\package.json'
16 error package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
16 error package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.
17 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

What I find interesting in the errors is that it is referring to "C:\Users\melon\package.json". Shouldn't it be looking in the project folder for package.json (which is c:\projects\mytodo)?

Another weird thing is that it is putting a folder called node_modules inside C:\Users\melon\node_modules. This folder contains grunt, grunt-karma, jasmine-core, karma and karma-jasmine. I already have the node_modules folder in C:\Users\melon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\

If I run the following manually, it installs successfully.

```
> bower install
```

If I run the following manually, it fails.

```
> npm install

gifsicle@2.0.1 postinstall C:\Projects\mytodo\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-gifsicle\node_modules\gifsicle
> node lib/install.js

module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\melon\lib\install.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3

...........
```

Here is some relevant PATH details:

```
PATH=C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\ant\bin;C:\Users\melon\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

I hope this is enough information for someone to show me where I have gone wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Since I can not comment yet (need 50 rep.), I'm posting this as an answer.

- Run Node.js as admin. This often helps a lot with those kind of errors.
- Your PATH variable is correct (Ruby is there, so is Git).
- I suggest you try npm install -g bower first because there seems to be something wrong with the package.

Have you already tried another generator (e.g. webapp)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That didn't fix the issue though. Created a new project folder, ran install -g bower and then yo webapp and got the same result.

Comment: Did you install the generator (npm install -g generator-webapp)? As a last resort you could go to your AppData folder and manually delete the bower folder (AppData > Roaming > npm > node_modules) and then reinstall bower by running npm install -g bower. I have no idea if this' ll help. It could break everything, but it can also help :)

Comment: I had a few generators already installed, including webapp. Tried deleting the bower folder and reinstalling bower. Still same error when I "yo webapp".